# How do I copy a cell that has an online hyperlink to another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to copy a cell that has an online hyperlink to another cell (while keeping the hyperlink intact), but every time I try this it just copies the value without the hyperlink.

=hyperlink does not work because that just hyperlinks to my cell's location; not the online hyperlink.

I tried to copy using vba but I ran into the same problem.

```
Worksheets("X").Range("AD17") = Worksheets("Y").Range("A2")
```

Comment: If you cut, it should keep the hyperlink - but it'll kill the original

Comment: `Worksheets("Y").Range("A2").Copy Worksheets("X").Range("AD17")`

Comment: @Tim: It was not my intention to CopyCat...

Comment: @FunThomas - great minds think alike ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Range.Copy` command will copy the text and the hyperlink:

```
Worksheets("Y").Range("A2").copy Worksheets("X").Range("AD17")
```